# Check exchange server max size in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

How can I check the *maximum size* of my exchange folder/account vial Outlook 2007?

**Note:** I don't want current size, which is available on my mailbox properties, but the maximum that number can grow to.

Comment: It will warn you when you get close to this limit. For example if your limit is 1.5GB and you are within a certain threshold (I don't know what it is off the top of my head) it will tell you, "your mailbox is at X.XGB at 1.5GB you will no longer be able to send emails" It has been awhile since I have seen the exact message but I know it states the max size.

Comment: @Kyle 1.5GB? ROFL!  Oh that's good, 1.5GB... we dream about 1.5GB here ...

Comment: Ross ouch... your IT dept needs to invest in a more robust SAND. We just put in a shiny new Equilogic :D.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the maximum size that the server has the mailbox set to in the mailbox size limit section, there is no way to determine that from Outlook.

If limits are not set on the server, then there is no maximum size.  Of course you will run out of room on the mailstore partition at some point, and you might have a size limit there (Exchange 2003 standard)...